# passing multiple values with comma seperation in cfqueryparam causing issue. it is paasing as index scan instead of index seek

Tags: coldfusion, cfquery, coldfusion-2018, cfqueryparam, coldfusion-administrator

I have a query where it passes the list value with comma separation using cfquery param. instead of index seek it is using index scan. I observed this is because of nvarchar 4000.

But the same query works in other environments, As we have 5 environments, CF version (exact), and DB version (exact)for all the environments. In 3 of the environments, the query works fine. In 2 environments we are getting 504 - Time out error.
Facing this issue only for tracknumber condition on where clause.

It may not be Code issue.
Is there any specific setting in CF Administrator for cfqueryparam or the setting we missed that may be causing this issue?

Code is below

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    PSOPackage PP with(nolock)
    JOIN PSO PINV with(nolock) ON PINV.PSOID = PP.PSOID 
    JOIN File F with(nolock) ON F.FileID = PINV.FileID 
    JOIN Company CY with(nolock) ON F.companyID = CY.companyID  
    left JOIN Package E ON PP.PackageID = E.PackageID
WHERE   
        <cfif form.PSOID neq 'None' and form.PSOID neq ''>
            PP.PSOID in 
                ( <cfqueryparam value="#form.PSOID#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" list="true" separator=","> )
        <cfelse>
            tracknumber  in 
                ( <cfqueryparam value="#form.tracknumber#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" list="true" separator=","> )
        </cfif>
ORDER BY pp.tracknumber, CY.abbr, f.file_Dt DESC
```

Tried passing the exact value like:

```
<cfelse>
    tracknumber  in 
        ('1V0Y780E0352033914','1M0Y780E0331023829','1S0Y780E0326482481','1P0Y780E0320555454',1X0Y770B0329555454 )
</cfif>
```

This works fine, With no error.

Comment: This won't be specific to CF. It's likely parameter sniffing - https://www.sqlshack.com/symptoms-of-the-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/

Comment: Given I think you are saying the column in question is an nvarchar 4000, any reason yer using `CF_SQL_VARCHAR` rather than `CF_SQL_NVARCHAR`?

Comment: the column in SQL in varchar type, I tried CF_SQL_NVARCHAR also. I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @haxtbh - for two environment i am using same DB, But in one environment it works fine with same DB , but won't work in other environment

Comment: It will be to do with the query plan and this can differ on each instance

Comment: "As we have 5 environement, In 3 of the environment query works fine. In 2 environment we are getting 504". What are the differences - CF version (exact), DB version (exact) - between the working and not working envs? Am inclined to agree with @haxtbh that this is an environmental issue, not a code issue.

Comment: Also pls update the original question when you answer these questions, don't just leave them in comments down here.

Comment: @AdamCameron sorry for not updating the request. This is My first time using stack overflow to ask questions. I am not used to it. I have Updated the Question now.
 I just wanted to tell you about my issue. The query is working fine. There is no issue with the query. That is why I have mentioned that it works fine in some envs.
wanted to know if there are any settings in Coldfusion Administrator related to cfqueryparam or any other settings that may be causing this issue.

Comment: @sangeetabhat there is nothing in CF. The query will be fine, even if you run it direct on the server. You have already answered your question by saying that putting the values directly works. This is because CF converts cfqueryparamed queries into stored procedures. The timeout is because the query is not using the right indexes due to parameter sniffing.

Answer (score 1):

If you run this query with an [execution plan](https://www.sqlshack.com/execution-plans-in-sql-server/), you'll see all the problems with this approach. You're sending in a list of strings that look like numbers and trying to compare those strings with numeric values. The other issue is that you could run into a limitation with the `IN` clause, which limits the number of items it can process from a list.

Instead, convert the list to a temp table using a [SQL function](https://www.sqlshack.com/converting-commas-or-other-delimiters-to-a-table-or-list-in-sql-server-using-t-sql/). You can define a primary key, insert the list values as `INT`, and add an index to that lone column. Change the `IN` to a `JOIN` against that table. This approach bypasses the eventual `IN` clause limitation and should speed up the query considerably.

When you [define a temp table](https://www.sqlshack.com/overview-and-performance-tips-of-temp-tables-in-sql-server/), use the local definition `#tempTable` and not the `@tempTable` approach.

I see you've got logic to run the query based on either a list of ID numbers or strings. You will need to define the temp table based on those conditions as `PSOID` is a list of `INT` values, and `tracknumber` is a list of strings.

For `PSOID`, it should look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP_PSOID
(
    PSOID int PRIMARY KEY
)
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_PSOID ON #TEMP_PSOID (PSOID);

INSERT INTO #TEMP_PSOID
SELECT *
FROM split_string(<cfqueryparam value="#form.PSOID#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" list="true" separator=",">);

SELECT *
FROM
    PSOPackage PP with(nolock)
    JOIN PSO PINV with(nolock) ON PINV.PSOID = PP.PSOID
    JOIN File F with(nolock) ON F.FileID = PINV.FileID
    JOIN Company CY with(nolock) ON F.companyID = CY.companyID
    left JOIN Package E ON PP.PackageID = E.PackageID
WHERE 
    INNER JOIN PP.PSOID = #TEMP_PSOID.PSOID
ORDER BY pp.tracknumber, CY.abbr, f.file_Dt DESC

DROP TABLE #TEMP_PSOID;
```

The `split_string` SQL function depends on your version of SQL Server.

I would create two stored procedures and call each one depending on the condition in your `WHERE` statement. But that may be more than you need at the moment.

Comment: Another approach is to manually create a SQL result using a CTE and then perform an inner join. (ie, WITH IDTable AS (SELECT ''1V0Y780E0352033914' AS ID UNION SELECT '1M0Y780E0331023829' AS ID) SELECT T.ID FROM MyTable T INNER JOIN IDTable I ON T.ID=T.ID

Answer (score 1):

Finally, the issue has been resolved. We have the Setting in ColdFusion Administrator in Datasource Setting.  CF2018 somehow is sending varchar parameters as nvarchar to SQL Server. So, indexes do not work correctly. We found that in the SQL monitor.

We checked the String Format check box in CF Admin, that checkbox is not enabled, so not sure why it would send varchar as nvarchar. We reset the CF admin setting, checked the box, saved, unchecked again, saved and reset the instance and it started working correctly.